# Lorentz transformation in system of unit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, units

In a system of units in which the velocity of light $c =1$,
$$x' = 1.25x - 0.75t$$
$$y'= y$$
$$z' = z $$
$$t'=1.25t -0.75x$$
is a Lorentz transformation. Why is this so? That is, how can we demonstrate that they represent a Lorentz transformation?

Comment: What definition of a Lorentz transformation did you learn? Does this satisfy that?

Comment: Yes it satisfy formula if i take relative velocity btw. Two systems x' and x as 0.6  but that's the question is it that much stupid qies?

Comment: Yes, these actually represent a valid Lorentz transformation. See my answer below @Aniket Thakur

Comment: Thanks a lot...i got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) where we consider motion in the x-direction only, is given by the equations

$$\tag 1 x’ = \gamma (x - vt)$$

$$\tag 2 t’ = \gamma (t -\frac{vx}{c^2} )$$
$$y’=y$$
$$z’=z$$

where the Lorentz factor,

$$\tag 3 \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

The question is, can these equations

$$x' = 1.25x - 0.75t\tag4$$ $$t'=1.25t -0.75x\tag5$$ $$y'= y$$ $$z' = z$$

be expressed in a form consistent with equations (1) and (2)?

If we first factor out the $1.25$ coefficient in the equations (4) and (5), we get

$$x’ = 1.25 (x - 0.60 \ t)$$
$$t’ = 1.25 (t - 0.60 \ x)$$

If we compare this to equations (1) and (2) we immediately deduce that $\gamma$ should be $1.25$ for the equations to be a valid Lorentz transformation. Upon inspection, we can also deduce that

$$\frac{v}{c^2} = 0.60$$ and $$v=0.6c$$

which are both consistent in units where the speed of light $c=1$. So now lets check by substituting this value of $v$ into equation (3) so that

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 -   \frac{(0.60c)^2}{c^2}}} = 1.25$$

which is also consistent with our original deduction of $\gamma$.

So the equations (4) and (5) *do* indeed represent a Lorentz transformation, with $\gamma=1.25$ and $v=0.6c$ (or just $v=0.6$ with $c=1$) for an observer watching an object moving at $60 \%$ the speed of light.

Comment: You should probably verify that the inverse transformation has the expected form.

Comment: Why? You automatically know it will.

Comment: Just to be a complete solution. ;) After all, that symmetry is a core element of the derivation of the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: You are right but that kind of additional algebra is not needed. But thanks.